# php code not executed inside .html file in Roundcube

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, roundcube

I'm trying to add php code inside the compose.html file in Roundcubemail.
I've .htaccess file in same directory as compose.html having like :

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

I've also prepare `httpd.conf` file present at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` Few lines which required here are as :

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
AllowOverride All
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

I've also tried restarting the `httpd` service. But still php code not executed in compose.html file. Can anybody please help me out with this?

Comment: This is probably by design.

Answer (score 2):

The templates of Roundcube are not evaluated within the directory. That's why your changes to `.htaccess` and `httpd.conf` didn't have any effect. They are rather evaluated by Roundcube template engine. Without digging deeper into the Roundcube core, the only option you have is their [Skin Template Markup Language](http://trac.roundcube.net/wiki/Doc_SkinML).